# Are `initialize` method and constructors the same?

Tags: ruby, constructor, initialization

Is Ruby [`initialize` method](http://ruby.activeventure.com/usersguide/rg/objinitialization.html) the same as constructors  in PHP or is it something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `initialize` method is equivalent to a constructor in other object-oriented languages.  Like everything in Ruby, there are some caveats, but I don't want to confuse the issue with nit-picking.  If you need a constructor, make an `initialize` method and it will get run whenever you call `MyClass.new`, before the instance is returned.

Answer (score 2):

In practice, people implement constructors as `initialize`, but to be accurate, the class method `new` is the constructor by default, and the instance method `initialize` is the method that is called by default whenever a new instance is created.